# What is the use of EAX register in the context of system calls in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the text book [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love](https://doc.lagout.org/operating%20system%20/linux/Linux%20Kernel%20Development%2C%203rd%20Edition.pdf), it is mentioned that (pg no. 101):

> The return value is sent to user-space also via register. On x86, it
>   is written into the eax register.

And in the text book [The Linux Programming Interface by Michael Kerrisk](https://moodle2.units.it/pluginfile.php/115306/mod_resource/content/1/The%20Linux%20Programming%20Interface-Michael%20Kerrisk.pdf), it is mentioned that (pg no. 88):

> Since all system calls enter the kernel in the same way, the kernel
>   needs some method of identifying the system call. To permit this, the
>   wrapper function copies the system call number into a specific CPU
>   register (%eax).

Then, what conclusion can I draw upon the utility of EAX register in system calls?

When the kernel comes across a system call the it copies the system call number to the EAX register, for which the value in the register is replaced by the return value of the system call at the time of return from the system call. Is this conclusion correct?

Answer (score 3):

[X86 Assembly/Interfacing with Linux](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux)

> ### Making a syscall
>
> For making a syscall using an interrupt, you have to pass all required
>   information to the kernel by copying them into general purpose
>   registers.
>
> Each syscall has a fixed number (note: the numbers differ between `int
>   $0x80` and `syscall`!). You specify the syscall by writing the number
>   into the eax/rax register.
>
> Most syscalls take parameters to perform their task. Those parameters
>   are passed by writing them in the appropriate registers before making
>   the actual call. Each parameter index has a specific register. See the
>   tables in the subsections as the mapping differs between `int $0x80`
>   and `syscall`. Parameters are passed in the order they appear in the
>   function signature of the corresponding C wrapper function. You may
>   find syscall functions and their signatures in every Linux API
>   documentation, like the reference manual (type man 2 open to see the
>   signature of the open syscall).
>
> After everything is set up correctly, you call the interrupt using
>   `int $0x80` or `syscall` and the kernel performs the task.
>
> The return / error value of a syscall is written to `eax`/`rax`.
>
> The kernel uses its own stack to perform the actions. The user stack
>   is not touched in any way.

So to sum up:

In user space:

- prepare the syscall by writing the parameters into specified registers
- put the syscall number into `eax`
- call the interrupt by `int $0x80` or `syscall`

In kernel space:

- the kernel reads the syscall number from `eax`
- reads the parameters from the specific registers
- performs the task (on it's own stack)
- writes the result in `eax`
- returns to control to user space

In user space again:

- you can find the result of the interrupt in the `eax` register